# onCreateOptionsMenu in SherlockFragment not called

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a SherlockFragment inside a SherlockFragmentActivity with ActionBar Navigation Drawer. I want to show different icons for each fragment. When i run the app y android 2.3.6 the method onCreateOptionsMenu is called, but when i run the app in android 4+ the method is not called.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

[This image is first section of an app that has that i want. 
Menu: dropdown, search collapsible and right sidemenu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G47u.png)

[And this is another section of the same app with the same navigation drawer and has different menu items for each fragment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sszCf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Which theme did you use? In your manifest, try to change your theme to Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.
or Holo

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Option menu is not use for later version.
Before API 11, there is no action bar. ActionBar Sherlock allows you to use the action bar on Android devices, Or you can use support library v7 in your project for using action bar. 
There is Action class as the standard solution for later android version. You can read this [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) tutorial for your android 4.0+ devices.

Comment: My theme is Theme.Serlock.Light. Your answer is wrong, im using ActionBarSherlock. If use your solution cause nullpointerexception.

Comment: Hughan i need to use the sherlock theme. If not cause a nullpointerexception. The problem is the method is called on android 2.3.6 but not in android 4+.

Comment: How can i add the menu items to actionbarsherlock for each fragment? Now understand me? Thanks.